# Run Code Analyzers in VSTS project build

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, code-analysis

In VSTS (hosted TFS) I have a build definition which uses MSBuild. What I would really like is to have pull requests annotated with any rule violation detections. However I can't get the analysers to work at all. What I've done so far;

1. Installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers in one of the projects that gets build
2. Verified that running "Analyze Code" in Visual Studio does output rule violations
3. All the `*.ruleset` files are not available on the self-hosted build agent, as it only has MSBuild installed (no full-fledged Visual Studio). For the same project as in point 1, I've also used a custom ruleset.
4. I have also build the project on a hosted build agent (which has VS2017 installed), but also to no avail.

With all of the above, the build log / build overview in VSTS doesn't list any rule violations. It's my understanding that the code analysis should be run automatically and the output should appear on the build overview page (i.e. `https://MYSITE.visualstudio.com/MYPROJECT/_build/index?buildId=XXX&_a=summary&tab=details`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code Analysis setting is based on the configuration and platform, so you need to make sure you build the project with the same configuration and platform that enabled code analysis on build.

[image]

[image]

You also could specify it in **MSBuild Arguments** of **MSBuild** task:

```
/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=..\RuleSets\MyMixedRecommendedRules.ruleset
```

Comment: Thank you! Trying it out now. Do you have any suggestions on how to reference the builtin Rulesets, which are normally installed together with Visual Studio? I could bundle them with my solution, but I don't know if that's the preferred setup?

Comment: Just specify the ruleset name if it is existing in the default folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets`): `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=AllRules.ruleset`

Comment: Otherwise, you can add it to the source control and map to build agent, shared folder is ok if can be accessible from build agent machine.

Comment: The rules are not installed as there's no Visual Studio on the build agent, only the build tools (MSBuild). So the options are 1. installing Visual Studio on the build agent, 2. adding the ruleset to source control, 3. copying them from my local machine. Is there a suggested method for installing the rulesets, without installing Visual Studio as a whole?

Comment: Ok thank you so far, I see analysis warnings being reported now in the logs. However they don't show up in my build overview, any suggestions?

Comment: What's the details in Issues of Build Summary? The warning should be there.

Comment: There are 999+ console items that start with `##[warning]`, however only 11 items are shown. And it looks like it only shows actual build warnings amongst these 11, no static code analysis warnings.

Comment: Feel free to open a new thread with the details of the issue.

Comment: Thank you so far. I've created a new question for the follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47260437/58107.