# Show Code Analysis warnings in VSTS

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, code-analysis

I've [setup Static Code Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47188775/58107) on my Visual Studio Team Services builds. I'm using the "MSBuild" build step for my solution and in the build logs it shows 999+ lines that start with `##[warning]`:

> 2017-11-09T13:52:34.7970784Z ##[warning]myfilename.cs(753,17): Warning CA2200: Re-throwing caught exception changes stack information.

When building with "system.debug" set to true, we also see that vso parses these warnings, and 999+ lines in the log show up like this:

> 2017-11-15T12:30:40.1964968Z ##[warning]myfilename.cs(28,33): Warning CS0109: The member 'Invoice.ColumnOptions' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
>   2017-11-15T12:30:40.1964968Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Warning;sourcepath=myfilename.cs;linenumber=28;columnnumber=33;code=CS0109;]The member 'XXX' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.

I would expect that the 999+ static analysis warnings would show up somewhere in the build overview (i.e. `https://MYSITE.visualstudio.com/MYPROJECT/_build/index?buildId=XXX&_a=summary&tab=details`). However it only shows 11 build warnings, nothing else. See also the screenshot below. How can I display the Static Code Analysis warnings in this build overview? Maybe even a summarised overview of the types of warnings that have triggered?

[image: Build overview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some months of working with VSTS, my experience is as follows;

- Code Analysis warnings will show up on the build summary
- VSTS will only show the first 11 warnings
- Thus, if the Code Analysis warnings are printed *after* 11 build warnings, they won't show up.

We've started using [Build Quality Checks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks) to fail the build when there are more warnings compared to the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just part of warnings in build display in the Issues section of build summary.

The workaround is that you can upload the code analysis result file (xml) through [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (`##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path`)and the content shall be added to build/release summary (Below Work items linked to associated changes section)

1. Add Powershell task
2. Call logging command to upload code analysis result

For example:

```
param(
[string]$p
)
Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]$p"
```

Arguments:

`-p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\WebAppAzureProfile\bin\WebAppAzureProfile.dll.CodeAnalysisLog.xml`

Comment: There's no file named `...CodeAnalysisLog.xml`. I also tried forcing this file by passing `/p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml`, to no avail. It seems like I'm hitting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41105813/58107.

Comment: Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true and queue build)

Comment: After some trial-and-error I resolved the issue with the xml output (I confused build warnings with static analysis output). However when uploading the XML, it tries to display the XML as HTML. The output is not so nice, to say the least. I guess we'd need some sort of conversion from those XML files to a nice HTML that can be embedded in the build overview? (XSLT?)

Comment: @bouke I think the Issue section can't display too many things, so it just display the first part of warning, in other words, if there are less warning (include code analysis warning) of build, it will display in the Issue section of build summary. Yes, the output is not nice, you need to do some sort of conversion from those XML files to a nice HTML, you can open a new thread to discuss how to convert xml to a nice HTML. On the other hand, since the original issue has been solved, you can accept this answer and answer.