# Display CFML CFLint results in TFS 2018 build Summary

Tags: tfs, coldfusion, tfsbuild, static-analysis, cfml

I'm trying to display static code analysis inside of a TFS build for a CI coldfusion build using [cflint](https://github.com/cflint/CFLint)

Within TFS I have a powershell script to run cflint to generate off a FindBug xml result file. Utilizing the Code coverage step in the Build process I'm unable to have the file be parsed, since it doesn't appear to conform to the JaCoCo format or the Cobertura file format.

Is there an alternative to get the results of the cflint to show in TFS I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you could create a **section** or a **tab** by writing your **own  extension** to display the info in build result report and build summary.

You can upload the **xml** result file as 'testrun-attachment' via REST-interface and got the pieces in place to show the summary values on  the build summary tab or on your own extended “test result” tab.
Here is a example with how to display opencover result for your reference: [vsts-opencover](https://github.com/RobertK66/vsts-opencover), finally will get the result as below:

[image]

How to write your own extension:

[Overview of extensions for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)

Some examples :

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples

This should definitely work, as you could see FindBugs standalone static analysis is supported during [**a Maven or Gradle build task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/standalone-tools?view=azure-devops). You could also refer the open source code of these tasks in GitHub.

---

Another way you could try to follow Starian's suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278262/5391065) by using logging commands to upload the generated code analysis files.

Comment: Thanks, for the time being I've ended up creating Powershell build steps for my build process to attach the output to the Build summary

Comment: For others that stumble upon this location I did end up creating an Azure DevOps Extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JoshKnutsonExtensions.devops-extension-cflint

Comment: @JoshKnutson That's pretty cool. Thanks for your terrific effort. Appreciate your contribution to Azure DevOps marketplace.